# % Chance mechanic

Tags: javascript, html, simplify

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generateNumber() {
document.getElementById("generated-id").innerHTML = getRandomInt (1, 10);
}

function stickForStamina(){
if (stamina > 0 && generateNumber() <= 1) {
stamina = stamina - 1;
stick = stick + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
}

}
```

Function so far for the % chance to find object i.e *stick*
I already fixed a few things in this question but still working on this after a day xD

This seems to work UPDATED % Chance code below

```
function stickForStamina(){
var num = getRandomInt(1, 10);
if (stamina > 0 && num <= 10) {
stamina = stamina - 1;
stick = stick + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
}
```

except now I have to figure a way to get rock in here at a 90% chance 9/10

```
function wildernessForStamina(){
var num = getRandomInt(1, 10);
if (stamina > 1 && num <= 9) {
stamina = stamina - 2;
stick = stick + 1;
rock = rock + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML = rock;
}
else if (stamina > 1 && num <=10) {
stamina = stamina - 2;
stick = stick + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
}
}
```

Figured it out. Any help on how I can write this better?

Comment: We could fix the code you're showing but I'd really like to advise you to read about the basics. [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript) [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Comment: yea I'm going through that webpage to help me out along with another webpage about incremental games. information has not clicked yet in my mind xD here is what I've been working on http://hexmerchant.github.io/ code wise my more updated code though is on my computer still

Comment: Well, one problem you have is that you declared `stickClick` inside `searchFunction` so only `searchFunction` has access to it and your other code does not.

Comment: oh ok I see my/an issue now. I'll tinker with if for another 30 min or so to see if I can fix it

Comment: 5 hours later xD I learned some stuff but I'll have to spend more time on it, since I'll still learning and teaching myself.

Comment: @Jonathan I worked on some of my code and have not made my search function yet, but I did start on the % chance function. I'm only having trouble with the function to give me a stick when I get the the number between 1-10. when generateNumber generates the number 1, I don't get a stick. Any clues?

Comment: I would use something like this.............. var num = getRandomInt(); document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = num < 10 ? "less than 10" : "greater than 10";

Comment: @Zze tried it out but I have not gotten it to work yet. 'num = my function getRandomInt();' but i don't know how 'document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = num < 10' does what I'm trying to figure out. I'm looking to gain "1 stick" at a 10% chance every click.

Comment: If getRandomInt() returns 0-100. Then this is essentially 10% whenever num < 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function wildernessForStamina(){
var num = getRandomInt(1, 10);
if (stamina > 1 && num <= 9) {
stamina = stamina - 2;
stick = stick + 1;
rock = rock + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML = rock;
}
else if (stamina > 1 && num <=10) {
stamina = stamina - 2;
stick = stick + 1;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
}
```

}

This Works. There is probably a way to shorten it but I'll continue other projects so I don't stay stuck on one thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple and straightfordward way for chance calculations using only Math.random()  method.

If you know that Math.random() returns nubmer from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive) you can calculate your chances like this:

If you want something to do in 50% cases then you can wrote:

```
if (Math.random() < 50/100f )
{
    // 50% = 50/100 = 0.5
    //do something
}
```

Same, if you want something to do in 0% cases (0% = 0/100 = 0) then you can wrote:

```
if (Math.random() < 0/100f )
{
    // this will never execute
    // minimum that random can return is 0 which can't be lower than 0/100 = 0
}
```

Same, if you want something to do in 100% cases (100% = 100/100 = 1) then you can wrote:

```
if (Math.random() < 100/100f )
{
    // this will allways execute
    // maximum that random can return is 0.9999999... which 
    // is always lower than 1
}
```

But, there are some other cases, you can wrote using this notation.

For example, if you want to do something three of four times, this can be wrote like:

```
if (Math.random() < 3/4f )
{
    // 3/4 = 0.75
    // 3/4 = 3*25 / 4*25 = 75 / 100 
}
```

or you want something to happened every 2 of 7 tries you write:

```
if (Math.random() < 2/7f )
{
   // you got it allready by now :)
}
```